# salesforce queryMore in ruby

Tags: ruby, salesforce, databasedotcom-gem

I have 50K records and i want to fetch  all records in 1000 batch size. In sql,i do something like  `limit 1000 offset x` but salesforces doesn't allow `offset` when it is greater than 2000. To overcome this problem, i used this trick

```
client.query("
  SELECT Id, Name__c, CreatedDate 
  FROM Product__c WHERE CreatedDate < "First-Returned-Created-Date" 
  ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC 
  LIMIT 1000    
")
```

and

But i got this error

```
Databasedotcom::SalesForceError: Bind variables only allowed in Apex code
```

So, how to apply `offset` in salesforce `SOQL`. I am using [databasedotcom-gem](/questions/tagged/databasedotcom-gem). I know about `queryMore()` method but for whatever reason i don't find any such API in ruby. Is there any such API available or something similar which will solve my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `next_page` function, it returns exactly what `queryMore` does.